# How do I get Smartface App Studio?

Tags: android, ide, smartface.io, mobile-development

I'm trying to download *Smartface App Studio* on my PC. Can anyone provide me with an offline installer of Smartface App Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smartface not supporting desktop development anymore. You can develop your projects on Cloud IDE. [www.smartface.io](http://www.smartface.io)

Comment: I was just on the Smartface web site, the tutorial says to click the "Log in for free" button, but... there is no button! Is Cloud IDE no longer available?

Comment: Free usage is not available for Smartface Cloud IDE. For licensed usage you can contact from https://www.smartface.io/contact/.